# javascript textarea maxlength issue with CR and CF

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, textarea

I have issue wit javascript maxlength calculation.

Javascript

```
function charCount(characters) {
    document.getElementById('citation').onkeyup = function () {
      var s = this.value;
      document.getElementById('sBann').innerHTML = (characters - s.length) + " characters left.";
    };
}
```

JSP:

```
<div class="FormRow">
<textarea class="textAreaLarge" rows="20" cols="180" name="citation" id="citation" maxlength="<%=maxCitationLength%>" onKeyUp="charCount(<%=maxCitationLength%>);"><%=citation%></textarea>
<div id="overDiv" style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden; z-index:1000;"></div>
<strong><div id="sBann" class="minitext"><% if (citation != null) { %><%= (maxCitationLength-citation.length()) %><%} else {%><%= (maxCitationLength) %><%}%> characters left.</div></strong>
</div>
```

My textarea has a maxlength of 1650 which should include the spaces too.
I have a create page.
While I type something in UI it takes into account the end of line as 1 character and allows upto 1650 characters and prevents user from entering more and its fine.
But on the server side end of line is taken as 2 characters for CR and CF and though JS calculates 1650 the data gets inserted with CR an CF and the length in DB is > 1650 say for example 1680.
On the DB side this field is a clob so i have no issues even if it stores  > 1650.

Now i have a edit screen where I have to display the same textarea and allow user to edit.
For the same example above where i entered 1650 but DB shows 1680, textarea in UI shows 1680 characters so the span on load which shows the no of charcters left is -20 because of the CR/CF value included on server side.

How do i deal with client side validation to include 2 characters for CR/CF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its carriage return `CR` and line feed `LF`. on Windows, if you `console.log()` textarea value it will not return `CR or \r` it only `\n`, I'm not sure on mac os.

You have duplicate events

```
onKeyUp="charCount(<%=maxCitationLength%>);"
// and
document.getElementById('citation').onkeyup = function () {
```

call it only once, in element attribute or script tag.

And to count CR/LF as two char use regex

```js
document.getElementById('citation').oninput = function(e) {
  var maxChars = 20;
  var sBann = document.getElementById('sBann');
  var s = this.value;

  // count linebreak
  var lineBreaks = s.match(/(?!\n$)\n/g) || '';
  var charCount = s.length + lineBreaks.length;
  if (charCount > maxChars) {
    this.value = s.slice(0, maxChars - lineBreaks.length);
    sBann.innerHTML = "0 characters left.";
    return false;
  }

  sBann.innerHTML = (maxChars - charCount) + " characters left.";

  console.log('s: ' + (s.length - lineBreaks.length), '|', 'line break (x2): ' + lineBreaks.length * 2);
  console.log('total: ' + charCount)
};
```

```html
<div class="FormRow">
  <textarea class="textAreaLarge" rows="10" cols="40" name="citation" id="citation" maxlength="20"></textarea>
  <div id="overDiv" style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden; z-index:1000;"></div>
  <strong><div id="sBann" class="minitext">20 characters left.</div></strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function charactersLeft(el) {
    var max = parseInt($(el).attr("maxLength"));
    var cur = $(el).val().length;
    return max - cur;
  }

  function allowType(el) {
    var result = true;
    if (charactersLeft(el) <= 0) {
      result = false;
    }
    return result;
  }

  function myTrim(el, str) {
    var value = $(el).val();
    value.replace(str, "");
    $(el).val(value);
  }

  $(".minitext > span").html(charactersLeft(".textAreaLarge"));

  $("#citation").on("keyup", function(e) {
    myTrim(this, "\r");
    $(".minitext > span").html(charactersLeft(".textAreaLarge"));
    if (!allowType(this)) {
      return false;
    }
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="FormRow">
  <textarea class="textAreaLarge" rows="20" cols="180" name="citation" id="citation" maxLength="1650"></textarea>
  <div id="overDiv" style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden; z-index:1000;"></div>
  <strong><div id="sBann" class="minitext"><span></span> characters left.</div></strong>
</div>
```

With `keyup`, we can return false to prevent the keystroke event.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. can you pls explain what you are trying to do here?

Comment: @JNPW I was working to address your question. In Windows, the End of Line (EOL) is represented by Carriage Return (CR) and New Line (NL), yet in Linux this is only New Line (NL). Either way it should only be 1 character. IF it's coming through as 2, you can remove the CR from each line.